# How to sum up fields per row and get its result then add it at the next row in a group in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

```
Group A
Item            Beginning Balance   Price   +12%    Ending Balance
Item One          0.00              100.00  12.00   112.00
Item Two          112.00            100.00  12.00   224.00
Item Three        224.00            100.00  12.00   336.00

Group B
Item            Beginning Balance   Price   +12%    Ending Balance
Item Four         0.00              100.00  12.00   112.00
Item Five         112.00            100.00  12.00   224.00
Item Six          224.00            100.00  12.00   336.00
```

How can I done these with Crystal Report, in these [tables](http://i60.photobucket.com/albums/h12/athina_15/cr_zps99352e9a.jpg) the only fields I have in my database are Group, Item and Price; and the rest is with crystal report.

Please help..

Comment: You'll need to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do here, I would do the following:

Create a formula for each line to add the 12% to the price eg
{priceUplift}=

```
{price}*1.12
```

You can use a variable field if the percentage changes eg {Percent} instead of the 1.12

---

Then Use the "3-formula trick" (google for more info if you don't know it)

Formula1: {Balance-Reset}

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar balance:=0;
```

Formula2: {Balance-Update}

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar balance;
balace:=balace+{priceUplifted}
```

Forumla3: {Balace-Display}

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar balance;
balace;
```

---

Insert the fields as follows:

```
Header       |ITEM            Opening-Balance   Price   %12          Closing-Balance 
Group 1 head |Group By{Group} {Balance-Reset}
Details      |{item}          {Balance-Display} {price} {Percentage} {Balance-Update}
```

---

I haven't tested this by that's how I would start the problem (I think it should work).
If there is a problem it will be to do with the Closing-Balance updating before Opening-Balance is displayed

Cheers B